# Why do not get any data from this callback function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I have tried to get this callback function to work. I get no error, but also no data. I have tested my  controller in Postman  and I get data.

```
 function GetSelected() {

     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/api/machine/',
         dataType: "JSON",
         data: "data",
         contentType: "Application/json;charset=utf-8",
         success: backcall  
     })
 };


 function backcall(data) {

     var selectmachine = $("#selectmachine").val();
     var Selectmachine = selectmachine + 1;

     alert('Data er:')

     $.each(function (data) {
         if (data.machinenumber == 3) {
             selected = data.selected;
             alert('Data er:' + selected)
         }
     })
 };
```

Comment: Where are you calling `GetSelected()`?

Comment: yes. I do.   logonmachine();
            logoffmachine();
            //logonmachine2();
            GetSelected();

Comment: Is the above statement in the same line? Then `GetSelected()` would be commented and not called thus.

Comment: It is not in the same line.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe of the selected question (although may still be a dupe)

Comment: @PeterGadeCarstensen what do you see if you add `console.log(data)` to `backcall()`? Also, is there any errors in the console?